# Reset store after refresh webpage

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a problem with the user object in nuxt authorization.

```
await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
   data: this.form
}).then((res) => {
   this.$auth.setUser(res.data.user)
   return response;
});
```

When I log in and redirect me to the subpage for the logged in. On the subpage, I display the user data that I received when logging in. The problem is that when I refresh the page, the user object becomes empty but the login status remains. What's the problem? I'm getting the user object with $ auth.user.username etc.

Comment: data in `store` is not persisted, will be reset once you reload browser. you need fetch it from backend

Comment: I think it's because of the setUser function. In nuxt auth module, there is the option to fetch user in nuxt.config.js.
have a look at this https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/local#user